# "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" error when trying to use react hooks (alpha)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to use the new React hooks feature I run into this annoying error message for some reason.

I followed the instructions on the documentation and upgraded react to the latest alpha version with `yarn add react@next`.

Answer (score 20):

I actually solved this issue! Most likely what you did to start using hooks was just updated react using `yarn add react@next` or something similar, but you probably didn't upgrade `react-dom` which is why you're getting this error.

**TLDR;** Upgrade `react-dom`!!

Comment: It seems hooks are not hot reloading.

Comment: I needed to upgrade the react lib.

Comment: Already updated react as well as react-dom to 16.8.6. Error is due to something else

Comment: Worked for me. You should mark this as the answer :)